# INTERSECT vs LEFT OUTER JOIN performance

Tags: sql, database-performance, query-performance, hana

we are using SAP HANA 1.0 SPS12. AS INTERSECT,MINUS,EXCEPT nodes are not available in graphical mode. We need to rely on LEFT OUTER JOIN or use below method-

https://blogs.sap.com/2014/03/02/thinking-in-hana-part-1-set-operators/

I have tables of volumes having 1 billion rows.

Can anyone suggest which method is better using LEFT OUTER JOIN or realising INTERSECT through UNION or using scripted view with INTERSECT operator from performance point of view?

Comment: You mean 100 *M*illion (10e8) rows ?

Comment: You can compare `left join + where col is null'  to `except`, but `intersect` is similar to an `inner join`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @PatrickHonorez - sorry i meant 1 billion rows

Comment: @dnoeth I was going to use **left join + where column is not null** as left joins are faster in HANA

Comment: *left joins are faster in HANA*, faster than *what*? And how can you know without testing?

Comment: @dnoeth Left outer join in faster than inner join sap HANA ...this is what lot of sap blogs say

Comment: How can a Left Join be "faster" than an Inner Join (besides possibly returning a different result)? Can you show those blogs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HANA 1 SPS 12 it’s perfectly OK to use table functions as part of graphical models.
Trying to emulate complex query operations usually worsens both performance and maintainability.
If your project „doesn’t allow“ using table functions the answer must be: fix that rule instead of producing a twisted view logic.

As for the „outer join is faster“ - that’s not true per se. Inner joins have a stricter semantic in that they have to be executed in every case, whereas outer joins allow to avoid the actual computation of the join in cases where the result set won’t be impacted by this. That means, when the conditions are fulfilled, outer joins can simply be avoided, which is of course faster than execution a join.